# Draw and get OpenSimplexNoise result

Tags: java, terrain, perlin-noise, simplex-noise

I want to generate a random terrain with OpenSimplexNoise. To start I just want to get a result and draw it to a window.

My question is now: How can I get the correct output of OpenSimplexNoise (cause there are many methods and I just don't know which is the correct one) and how to draw this result.

It should look like this: 
[image]

```
    public double[][] generateMap(long seed, int width, int height) {
        double[][] map = new double[width][height];

        // start generating things here, just how?
        OpenSimplexNoise simplex = new OpenSimplexNoise(seed);

        return map;
    }

    public void drawMap(double[][] map, Graphics g) {
        for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++) {
                Color color = new Color(); // how to get the color here?
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the current code I've got.

Here is the link to OpenSimplexNoise for anyone who needs it:
https://gist.github.com/KdotJPG/b1270127455a94ac5d19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually only 3 public methods - one for each for 2D, 3D & 4D noise.
Since you're filling a 2D array for your map , use the 2D noise eval method,
something like this:

```
for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
   for(int y=0<y<height; y++){
      map[x][y] = simplex.eval(x, y);
   }
}
```

Later on, you can generate a color from the map values as follows:

```
Color color = Color.color(map[x][y], ma[x][y], map[x][y]);
```

The author also provides example usage code in `OpenSimplexNoiseTest`; he's using the 3D eval method, but always holding the z coord at zero. My guess is the example code was written before he added the 2D & 4D implementations. At any rate, it still works, but it might be a little slower than directly using 2D.

Comment: Color constructor noes not accept double.

Comment: You'd likely want to do something like `Math.floor(((map[x][y]-min)/(max-min))*255d)` (i.e. make it go from 0 to 255)